# viewModelScope unresolved reference

Tags: android, kotlin, android-lifecycle, android-architecture-components, android-viewmodel

I was trying to:
import androidx.lifecycle.viewModelScope and I get unresolved reference. I tried old StackOverflow links mentioning that I had to change implementation's version to 2.2.0 or higher or insert runtime dependence but I already have done this, as it is shown below.

These are my dependencies and plugins

```
    // Navigation
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.2.2'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.5'

    // Room
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.3.0"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.3.0"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:2.3.0"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.room:room-testing:2.3.0"

    // Lifecycle


    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:2.3.1"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.1"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.3.1"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.1"


    // Kotlin
    api "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.4.2"
    api "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.4.2"
```

Comment: oops I forgot to add the plugins:  'kotlin-kapt', id 'kotlin-android-extensions', id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin' plus the default plugins

Comment: Try rebuild-clean your project most likely to be solved there plus make sure you have used inside member method of ViewModel implemed class

Comment: Oh now it worked I forgot to extend the ViewModel() class. I just started learning Room rn and I'm a dumbass, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

As per the [`viewModelScope` documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/lifecycle/package-summary#(androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel).viewModelScope:kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineScope), `viewModelScope` is an [extension property](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/extensions.html#extension-properties) on the `ViewModel` class.

Therefore to use `viewModelScope`, make sure you are within a class that extends `ViewModel`.